# Web API Individual Account Authentication and exsiting database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

in visual studio 2013 i have a solution with 2 projects:

```
-An entity framework project "database first" 
-A web api project with individual accounts authentication, with a reference to the entity framework project
```

In Sql Server i have an existing database and the entity framework project is generated from the database.
Now in the web api project, inside the Web.config i have type the following connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="StrokeInEntities" connectionString="metadata=res: ...... />
   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source ....... />
</connectionStrings>
```

where:

- the DefaultConnection is used for the authentication (and the web api generate in my existing database the tables dbo.AspNetUsers, dbo.AspNetUserRoles etc...
- StrokeInEntities connection is used for access to the exsiting tables from the web api controller

Now the problem is that when i access to an exsisting table from my web api controller, i see in the db that originate a new table with dbo prefix. For example if i access to table "People" the db create a new table dbo.People.

How can remove this effect?